# I can't add ajax controls to Visual Studio 2010

Tags: ajax, visual-studio-2010

I can't add AJAX controls to VS2010 rc. I try to drag it to design view, but nothing happens, code remains unchanged. Where is a problem here? Should I install manually ajax toolbox to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this article:

http://blogs.msdn.com/webdevtools/archive/2009/05/26/using-microsoft-ajax-control-toolkit-with-visual-studio-10-beta-1.aspx

Finally look at this: http://blogs.msdn.com/webdevtools/archive/2009/05/26/using-microsoft-ajax-control-toolkit-with-visual-studio-10-beta-1.aspx

More specifically

> "The AjaxControlToolkit you can
>   download from the web is for 3.5 fx.
>   It can work with a 4.0 framework, but
>   you can't see some functionality such
>   as no smart task, or you can't drag
>   and drop onto a supported control, for
>   VS 2010 Beta2. You need to retarget
>   the toolkit source to use 4.0 fx and
>   rebuild it."

Comment: Didn't work. trying to add Ajax assembly, I select all ajax controls to be imported, click OK and nothing happens, no error msg, no items added into the toolbar.. :(

Answer (score 2):

Reset the toolbox and add again all your customized server control and will be fixed

Answer (score 0):

After the file has been downloaded (and extracted), you may need to UNBLOCK the AjaxControlToolKit.Dll